# I'm sending a request to a Rest Api from Xamarin Forms and it does not see the string

Tags: c#, api

I created a Login Class where I save a token. When I'm trying to send the token to query the REST API, it does not see it. I've checked and I'm receiving the token. Please if some of you could help me to check the issue I would be very thankful.

This is the class where I save the token.

```
public class Login
{
    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public string status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("message")]
    public string message { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("jwt")]
    public string token { get; set; }
}
```

This is the button where I call the method:

```
Repository ccs = new Repository();

public LinkPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public async void OnUpdateUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {     
        Login tokenreq = new Login();

        userInfo tokeninfo = ccs.postUserInfo(tokenreq.token).Result;
        Dialogs.ShowLoading(tokeninfo.Message.ToString()); ;
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        Dialogs.HideLoading();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Login Error", ex.Message, "Intente de nuevo mas tarde");
    }
}
```

This is the method:

```
public async Task<userInfo> postUserInfo(string token)
{
    object param = new { token = token };
    var jsonObj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(param);

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        StringContent content = new StringContent(jsonObj.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
        {
            RequestUri = new Uri("https://crmpuntos.oliviadirect.co/services/user/info.php"),
            Method = HttpMethod.Post,
            Content = content
        };

        var response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
        string dataResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        userInfo result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<userInfo>(dataResult);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since my previous answer was deemed wrong, there is some more info needed, since your question is not quite clear. You wrote "The API does not see the token", but in your comment "for some reason it is not serializing the object". Have you verified that the token is not serialized?

Comment: I've tried the bit you are using for serialization and the token was serialized correctly.

Comment: BTW, there are some issues with your code: Don't use `Result` let alone in an `async` method. Use `string dataResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` and `UserInfo tokeninfo = await ccs.PostUserInfo(tokenreq.token)`. Type, Method and property names are ussually written in pascal case in C#, hence it should be `Status`, `Message`, `Token`, `PostUserInfo` and `UserInfo`. Every C# developer looking at your code will thank you if you follow a minimal set of conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

I needed to store the token in SecureSTorage, after that everything worked perectly

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

```cs
Login tokenreq = new Login();

userInfo tokeninfo = ccs.postUserInfo(tokenreq.token).Result;
```

The `Login` class is instantiated just before you are accessing `tokenreq.token`. After the instantiation, all of `status`, `message` and `token` are `null`. Hence you are effectively calling

```cs
userInfo tokeninfo = ccs.postUserInfo(null).Result;
```

Obviously, when trying to serialize the token, there *is* no token to serialize. The fields of a class are set for each instance (unless they are static) so if you are setting the token in one instance

```
var login = new Login();
login.token = ccs.Login(username, password); // or whatever
```

it's not magically set in each instance of the `Login` class. You'll need some mechanism to store and retrieve the token.

If you want to develop software, you should *really really* get the basics right. That a field or property is not set automatically, just because it has been set in any other instance of the class, is OOP 101. Please do yourself a favour and read, read, read. Writing code along the process of reading is not only not wrong, but rather essential, but the code you provided looks as if it's meant to be used in a real world scenario and for that purpose the quality is far from sufficient.

**Side note**

There are some issues with your code: Don't use `Result` let alone in an `async` method. Use

```cs
string dataResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

and

```
UserInfo tokeninfo = await ccs.PostUserInfo(tokenreq.token);
```

Type, Method and property names are ussually written in pascal case in C#, hence it should be `Status`, `Message`, `Token`, `PostUserInfo` and `UserInfo`. Every C# developer looking at your code will thank you if you follow a minimal set of conventions.